# corrupted pg_class data? ghost index on non-existent table

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.3

I'm running some issues with creating/dropping indexes. 
So originally I had

```
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS ros_tmp_schoolid_IX;
```

and then

```
CREATE INDEX ros_tmp_schoolid_IX on ros.sometable USING btree (somecolumn);
```

and it complains that index already exists

then I switched my method to

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM   pg_class c
            JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
            WHERE  c.relname = 'ros_tmp_schoolid_IX'
            AND    n.nspname = 'ros')
THEN
    DROP INDEX ros_tmp_schoolid_IX;
END IF;
```

but I'm still getting index does not exist error...so I looked into pg_class table, I was able to find a record for that index.

I have also tried all of the following and none worked:

1. dropping the table;
2. reindex/analyze/vacuum the whole database
3. reindex table pg_class

I'm using Postgresql 9.3 with Rails(4.1.5). This happens randomly when running my test suite...when processing large chunks of data, I'm using temp tables and dropping them after the job is finished.

I'm not sure what might have caused the issue. Is there anything else I should look into?

Thanks!

=========

also, I found a couple of more in pg_class, I think I need a way to clean it up.

So I tried to create the index with the same name, on a different table, and it was successful. 
But..when I try to drop it again...I'm getting relation does not exist error. I tried to run the CREATE INDEX query right after that, then it's saying the relation already exists...postgres can't decide...

Comment: `DROP INDEX IF EXISTS "ros_tmp_schoolid_IX";` (and in the future: avoid mixed case identifiers; they are a PITA, IMHO)

Comment: Hello joop, it's telling me skipping because index does not exist. What I'm trying to do here is 1. clean up invalid records in pg_class; 2. recreate this index. (reindex does not work because index does not exist). Thanks for the naming suggestion.

Comment: What does `(SELECT 1 FROM   pg_class c JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace WHERE  c.relname ILIKE 'ros_tmp_schoolid_IX' AND    n.nspname = 'ros')` result in ?

Comment: it returns 1 :) @joop also `select *` returns the index's name and oid and stuff.

Comment: now try `SELECT c.relname  FROM pg_class c JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace WHERE c.relname ILIKE 'ros_tmp_schoolid_IX' AND n.nspname = 'ros' ;` And use **exactly**  that name **in double quotes** in your delete index statement.

Comment: ERROR:  index "ros_tmp_schoolid_IX" does not exist

Comment: btw that query did return the correct name. i copy pasted it into the drop statement.

Comment: are you sure that the question is for rails?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ well true it's mostly related to SQL, but this problem only happens when I run my rails test suite...will remove the tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short version**: you want to include the name of the schema:

```
 DROP INDEX IF EXISTS ros.ros_tmp_schoolid_IX;
```

---

**Explanation**:

When creating an index, it goes automatically into the same schema as the table that is specified. A schema name is not even allowed, as the [doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createindex.html) indicates:

> No schema name can be included here; the index is always created in
>   the same schema as its parent table

However when dropping an index, the schema needs to be specified if it's not in the search path. Presumably `ros` is not in `search_path` in your case.

Also as mentioned in the comments, an index name  with capital letters but not enclosed in double quotes will be converted to lower case, so following `CREATE INDEX ros_tmp_schoolid_IX ...` you'll find `ros_tmp_schoolid_ix` in `pg_class.relname`